# save an image with names defined as a string variable

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to saving the image to a folder using the following code segment.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(100))
current_path = os.getcwd()
result_path = os.path.join(current_path, "result")
filename_1 = str('FullData' + 'experiment_1.png')
fig.savefig('{}\\filename_1'.format(result_path))
```

I used the `filename_1` to represent some long strings. After running the code, the saved image was named as `"filename_1.png"` instead of `"FullDataexprement_1.png"` as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, in the `savefig()` call, `filename_1` is interpreted as a string not a variable.
So you are using the string "filename_1" as the filename when calling the method, instead of using the value of the `filename_1` variable.

Modify:

```
fig.savefig('{}\\filename_1'.format(result_path))
```

To:

```
fig.savefig('{}\\{}'.format(result_path, filename_1))
```